# Regex to match with comma and equal characters in utf8

Tags: php, regex

How can I regex match with this format?

a1=q1,a2=q2,a3=q3,a4=q4
(this is correct sample and a characters will be utf-8)

a1=q1,a2=q2,a3=q3,a4=q4, (faulty sample)

If string have last comma character, how can I exclude last comma in regex?

My sample php code is:

```
$pattern="/^(\p{L}\=\p{L},?)*$/u";
$string1="a1=q1,a2=q2,a3=q3,a4=q4"; //correct
$string2="a1=q1,a2=q2,a3=q3,a4=q4,"; //incorrect
if (preg_match($pattern,$string1,$m)) { echo "correct"; } else { echo "incorrect"; }
if (preg_match($pattern,$string2,$m)) { echo "correct"; } else { echo "incorrect"; }
```

Comment: or with a word boundary like this: [`^(?:\w+=\w+,?\b)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/tQqHxs/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this expression,

```
(?!.*,$)([\p{L}\p{N}]+=[\p{L}\p{N}]+),?
```

might work, which here

```
(?!.*,$)
```

we would just add a not ending with comma statement.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJfVoy/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/tJfVoy/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?!.*,$)([\p{L}\p{N}]+=[\p{L}\p{N}]+),?/m';
$str = 'a1=q1,a2=q2,a3=q3,a4=q4
a1=q1,a2=q2,a3=q3,a4=q4,';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, working good with (ç=c,ğ=g,ı=i,ö=o,ş=s,ü=u,) utf8 characters. And also my second regex working too.. `/^(\p{L}\=\p{L},?)*[^,]+$/u`

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, all you need to match last group without any `,`,

You can use this

```
^(\p{L}+\d+\=\p{L}+\d+,)*(\p{L}+\d+\=\p{L}+\d+)$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/MEXDQm/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also i did try more examples and I guess i found second solution. `/^(\p{L}\=\p{L},?)*[^,]+$/u` I should use which one?

Comment: Thank you again for your answer but didn't work with some utf8 characters. (ç=c,ğ=g,ı=i,ö=o,ş=s,ü=u,)

Comment: @webmaster there was no such example added in question neither information regarding digit to be optional `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` if you want digits to be optional you can simply change `\d+` to `\d*`